# Get the value of the token from authentication in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have made a customized token Authentication for my app. It is based on a specific model that stores the tokens that I will be generating.

```
class ApiKeyAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
   keyword = "api-key"

   def get_token_from_auth_header(self, auth):
       auth = auth.split()
       #validations here

   def authenticate(self, request):
       auth = get_authorization_header(request)
       token = self.get_token_from_auth_header(auth)

       if token:
           return self.authenticate_credentials(token)

   def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
       try:
           token = TokenModel.objects.get(key=key)
       except TokenModel.DoesNotExist:
           raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Invalid Api key.")

       user = User.objects.first()
       return (user, token)
```

Is there a possibility to get the values of the `token` that was returned upon `authenticate_credentials`? I have to access a field from that model ( `TokenModel` ) on the `views.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do some research on this to see what is the best way in accessing the returned parameters. There is no need to manually set the `token` instance on your request. You can access it through `request.auth`. With that, you can access the passed parameters on your views.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add an attribute to the request object.

```
def authenticate(self, request):
   auth = get_authorization_header(request)
   token = self.get_token_from_auth_header(auth)

   if token:
       usr, tok = self.authenticate_credentials(token)
       setattr(request, 'token', tok)
       return (usr, tok)
```

It is not the best nor the prettiest solution, but it does allow you to retrieve the `TokenModel` from the `request` object in your `views.py`.